# How to execute another jquery animation after another?

Tags: jquery

So I want to take an image and have move to the left 10px and top 10px THEN move to the left -10px and top -10px.

The following code demonstrates what I have so far. What am I doing wrong?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8NvYP/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#floating_island').animate({
        'left': '10px',
        'top': '10px'
    },500,'linear',function(){
        'right': '10px',
        'top': '-10px'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the animate complete callback function, you need to call the `animate()` again with the desired arguments

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#floating_island').animate({
        'left': '10px',
        'top': '10px'
    }, 500, 'linear', function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'right': '10px',
            'top': '-10px'
        }, 500)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SKKmJ/)

Comment: Much simpler to just use chaining since animation calls automatically go in the fx animation queue so you don't have to link them with completion functions.

Answer (score 0):

you could also chain the [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#floating_island').animate({
        'left': '10px',
        'top': '10px'
    },500,'linear').delay(500).animate({
        'right': '10px',
        'top': '-10px'
    },500);
});
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCF7m/)

Answer (score 0):

you can chain them like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#floating_island').animate({
        left: '+=10',
        top: '+=10'
    },500,'linear').animate({
        left: '-=10',
        top: '-=10'
    },500,'linear');
});
```